# Zbar not releasing camera(issue on kitkat) android

Tags: android, android-camera, zbar

I am having a screen where i am using zbar to scan barcode, after that, is start a new activity onto which i take picture using surfaceView.
But in second activity camera is giving an exception

> RuntimeException: Cannot connect to camera service.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

> It is working for lolipop, marshmallow and other higher versions

Comment: Did you find any solution?